# Unable to lock Dropbox error while deploying in Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, dropbox

I am not able to deploy to Heroku through Dropbox because of the following error:

```
Unable to lock Dropbox, if the problem persist, please re-link the app
```

Even after relinking, it gives the same error.

Anybody faced this issue.

What can be done to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working after resolving conflicts in Dropbox file merge.

Comment: i am having this issue, what did you have to do to get it working?

Comment: There were few conflict files created within the application folder. I had to remove conflict files. Also clearing the application folder and adding all files freshly within the application folder solves this issue.